# Singular values sorted in descending order using svds from scipy.sparse.linalg

Tags: python, scipy, sparse-matrix, svd

I am applying SVD to a large sparse matrix in Python. I am using svds from the scipy.sparse.linalg package. The singular values are sorted from an ascending order, so the singular vectors are arranged corresponding to the ascending singular values. I am wondering if there is an option to output the singular values in a descending order, so that the singular vectors are also arranged corresponding to the descending singular values? Below is just a sample code:

```
from scipy.sparse.linalg import svds
from scipy import sparse
X = numpy.random.uniform(size = [40, 20])
X = scipy.sparse.csc_matrix(X)
u, s, vt = svds(X, 10, which = 'LM')
```

I have tried sparsesvd python library. The runtime of sparsesvd is much longer compared to svds on the sample matrix. So I am not considering using sparsesvd. The regular svd package in scipy does not work for sparse matrix. Thank you!

Comment: Are you trying to calculate the smallest singular values, *or* to output the N larges singular vectors in a different order? If the latter, then `u = u[:,::-1]; s = s[::-1]; vt = vt[::-1,:]` (or something similar) should be enough.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are now looking for the 10 largest singular values and receive them in ascending order along with the left and right singular vectors. If you want n smallest values, just change the `which` keyword into `SM`.

However, I understand you receive the correct singular values but in a wrong order. There is no switch in the function to do that, but the vectors and the values can be rearranged with the following rule: *the first n columns of u and the first n rows of vt have to be kept in the same order as the singular values*.

So, reversing the singular values:

```
n = len(s)
# reverse the n first columns of u
u[:,:n] = u[:, n-1::-1]
# reverse s
s = s[::-1]
# reverse the n first rows of vt
vt[:n, :] = vt[n-1::-1, :]
```

This is very simple (as also given by pv in his comment), but the trick is not to rearrange the complete matrices, just the relevant rows/columns. And, naturally, any permutation will do, so in general (`perm` is the permutation vector):

```
u[:,:n] = u[:, perm]
s = s[perm]
vt[:n, :] = vt[perm, :]
```